# How to place subfigure caption on the side?

Tags: floats, positioning, captions, subfloats, subcaption

Is there some way to tell `subfig` package to place subfigure captions to the left or to the right of subfigures? There is `sidecap` package which does it for the main captions, but it does not affect subfigure captions.

Or, if `subfig` does not have this options, which way to do it is the best? I tried to use `tabular` environment inside the figure, but there were some problems with alignment inside cells.

Comment: I am the maintainer of subfig package. You can request new feature with full details and I will make it avaliable in a few days. https://bitbucket.org/vafa/subfig/issues?status=new

Comment: Thanks for the offer, Vafa, I filed the request: https://bitbucket.org/vafa/subfig/issue/1/option-to-place-subfigure-caption-on-the . I hope the description is clear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The subcaption package offers a command called `\subcaption` which typesets a sub-caption alone and has the same syntax as `\caption`. You can place this command where you want, i.e. also beside a figure.

Addendum 2011-01-19, Example code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\parbox[b]{.5\linewidth}{\Large
Insert picture here --
Insert picture here --
Insert picture here --
Insert picture here}%
\hspace{.1\linewidth}%
\parbox[b]{.4\linewidth}{%
\subcaption{This is just a short document to show that
we can place the sub-caption where we want to.}}
\caption{Main caption.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Furthermore the floatrow package offers stuff like that (and more).

Comment: As far as I understand, ``subcaption`` package only allows you to tune style, but not the relative position of the subcaption.

Comment: No, that is not true. Since you can place the \subcaption where YOU want it, and because the sub-caption will be typeset where you have placed the \subcaption command, you have total control about its position. Will do some handicraft work right now... (Please hold the line...)

Comment: From your code, it seems that `\subcaption` by itself does not have options to control its position and one needs to use `\parbox` (whatever that is) to place it - is this correct?

Comment: +1, just used this solution myself. Although I had to put some thought in getting all the optional parameters of `parbox` correct to obtain my desired result.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution with `tabular` environment, which is a bit messy, but works. It is based on [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467351/latex-tabular-vertical-alignment-to-top).

```
\def\imagetop#1{\vtop{\null\hbox{#1}}}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{tabular}{l l}
    \imagetop{\includegraphics{figure1.eps}} & \imagetop{(a)} \\
    \imagetop{\includegraphics{figure2.eps}} & \imagetop{(b)}
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Main caption.}
\end{figure}
```