# How can I reproduce the figure with each picture labeled by a lowercase letter?

Tags: floats, arrays

Here is the figure I am trying to reproduce. 
[image: Figure 2]

I was able to get the figure without the lowercase labels with the following code:

```
\begin{figure}
    $$\begin{array}{cl}
        \includegraphics[height=2cm]{image1.jpg} &
        \includegraphics[height=2cm]{image3.jpg} \\
        \includegraphics[height=2cm]{image2.jpg} &
        \includegraphics[height=2cm]{image4.jpg}
    \end{array}$$
    \caption{$(a)-(d)$ are cool}
\end{figure}
```

I can't figure out out to get the letters to appear at the bottom left of each picture. Can anyone help?

Comment: The figure you posted looks like they just wrote (a) - (d) right before `\includegraphics` command. A better way to do it would be with the subcaption package. Take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9260/how-to-place-subfigure-caption-on-the-side on how to post a subcaption on the side.

Comment: Lol I've tried everything except placing (a) - (d) before \includegraphics. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Can I ask where the problem comes from, please?

Comment: This looks like a "do my homework for me" question in its current state.

Comment: @tohecz - it comes from a document my professor gave us to learn latex. I think he received it from a friend of his.

Comment: @PaulGessler - If you say so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a minor modification to your MWE, but better output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\[
\begin{array}{rlrl}
(a) & \includegraphics[height=2cm]{image1.jpg} & (b)& \includegraphics[height=2cm]{image3.jpg} \\
(c) & \includegraphics[height=2cm]{image2.jpg} & (d)& \includegraphics[height=2cm]{image4.jpg}
\end{array}
\]
\caption{(a)--(d) are cool}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]

Comment: While this works, it is not a good advice at all. You misuse math-mode and `array` for something that's quite unrelated. The usage of minus `$-$` instead of an n-dash `--` is wrong, too. After all, `a,b,c,d` are not math symbols, if they have to be italic, one should use `\textit{a}` or `{\itshape a}`.

Comment: You should stick to the requirements of the OP. The OP asked for using `array` within a `figure` environment. Also I didn't pay much attention to `$(a)-(d)$` to direct the OP to the main concept. I edited it anyway. Thanks

Comment: The fact that someone asks for a dirty thing doesn't mean we can't at least explain that it is dirty.

Comment: @AboAmmar The usage of `$$` and `array` by the OP is probably due to inexperience; `\centering` and `tabular` are the tools to use.

Answer (score 3):

It is better to use `tabular` than `array`:

```
\documentclass[demo]{article}    %% remove demo in your file
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}  %% gives valing key
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{r@{\hspace{2pt}}lr@{\hspace{2pt}}l}
    (a) & \includegraphics[valign=b,height=2cm]{image1.jpg} &
    (b) & \includegraphics[valign=b,height=2cm]{image3.jpg} \\
    (c) & \includegraphics[valign=b,height=2cm]{image2.jpg} &
    (d) & \includegraphics[valign=b,height=2cm]{image4.jpg}
\end{tabular}
\caption{(a)--(d) are cool}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No neeed to complicate your life for this sort of things

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
(a)\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2cm]{image1}%
(b)\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2cm]{image1}

(c)\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2cm]{image1}%
(d)\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2cm]{image1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Good idea, but spacing is all wrong.

Comment: @egreg Depends from which angle you looking at it. These are actually inlined figures so let TeX take over. Otherwise `\vspace* and \hspace*` would do the trick. Can't believe you didn't upvote:)